# Spring boot doesn't load data to initialize database using data.sql

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to load some data when Spring boot is starting, but data is not getting loaded to database though I do not get any error. Below is the code

```
spring:
  debug: true
  datasource:
  username: root
  password: ****
  url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/customer_registration_service?connectTimeout=100
  driver-class-name: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
  initialize: true
  data: data-mysql.sql
  validation-query: SELECT 1
  test-on-borrow: true
jpa:
  database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
  properties:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
      naming-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringNamingStrategy
```

I have the `data-mysql.sql` file located at `src/main/resources`

In-order to force error, I tried deliberately giving a wrong file name, still I do not get any real error.So it seems like Spring is ignoring the setting altogether

EDIT:

Here is the startup log

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building customer-registration 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ customer-registration >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ customer-registration ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ customer-registration ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ customer-registration ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/cheruveettilz/Projects/innovationday/customer-registration-service/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ customer-registration ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ customer-registration <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ customer-registration ---

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.2.RELEASE)

2017-07-13 19:41:37.055  INFO 83740 --- [           main] c.b.s.customer.registration.Application  : Starting Application 
2017-07-13 19:41:37.058  INFO 83740 --- [           main] c.b.s.customer.registration.Application  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-07-13 19:41:37.106  INFO 83740 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4883e67d: startup date [Thu Jul 13 19:41:37 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-07-13 19:41:37.792  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]]
2017-07-13 19:41:38.278  INFO 83740 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4b8a61c9] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-13 19:41:38.521  INFO 83740 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-07-13 19:41:38.530  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-07-13 19:41:38.531  INFO 83740 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-07-13 19:41:38.598  INFO 83740 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-07-13 19:41:38.598  INFO 83740 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1495 ms
2017-07-13 19:41:38.713  INFO 83740 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-07-13 19:41:38.716  INFO 83740 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-13 19:41:38.716  INFO 83740 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-13 19:41:38.716  INFO 83740 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-13 19:41:38.716  INFO 83740 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-13 19:41:39.080  INFO 83740 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-07-13 19:41:39.094  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-07-13 19:41:39.163  INFO 83740 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-07-13 19:41:39.165  INFO 83740 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-07-13 19:41:39.166  INFO 83740 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-07-13 19:41:39.206  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-07-13 19:41:39.315  INFO 83740 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2017-07-13 19:41:39.841  INFO 83740 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-07-13 19:41:40.513  INFO 83740 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4883e67d: startup date [Thu Jul 13 19:41:37 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-07-13 19:41:40.575  INFO 83740 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-07-13 19:41:40.576  INFO 83740 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-07-13 19:41:40.598  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-07-13 19:41:40.598  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-07-13 19:41:40.609  INFO 83740 --- [           main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in repositoryRestExceptionHandler
2017-07-13 19:41:40.657  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-07-13 19:41:40.801  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerAdapter   : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4883e67d: startup date [Thu Jul 13 19:41:37 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-07-13 19:41:40.816  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-07-13 19:41:40.816  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-07-13 19:41:40.816  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-07-13 19:41:40.817  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReferenceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-07-13 19:41:40.817  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[PATCH || PUT || POST],consumes=[application/json || application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.createPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<java.lang.Object>,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-07-13 19:41:40.817  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReferenceId(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
2017-07-13 19:41:40.819  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.optionsForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-07-13 19:41:40.819  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-07-13 19:41:40.819  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchesResource org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.listSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-07-13 19:41:40.819  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders)
2017-07-13 19:41:40.819  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearchCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
2017-07-13 19:41:40.820  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.optionsForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
2017-07-13 19:41:40.820  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
2017-07-13 19:41:40.821  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.optionsForRepositories()
2017-07-13 19:41:40.822  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.headForRepositories()
2017-07-13 19:41:40.822  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryLinksResource> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.listRepositories()
2017-07-13 19:41:40.823  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.optionsForCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-07-13 19:41:40.824  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-07-13 19:41:40.824  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-07-13 19:41:40.824  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResourceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-07-13 19:41:40.824  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[POST],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-07-13 19:41:40.825  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.optionsForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-07-13 19:41:40.825  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-07-13 19:41:40.825  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<?>> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-07-13 19:41:40.826  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PUT],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.putItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-07-13 19:41:40.826  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PATCH],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.patchItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException
2017-07-13 19:41:40.827  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.deleteItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2017-07-13 19:41:40.831  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile],methods=[GET]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.listAllFormsOfMetadata()
2017-07-13 19:41:40.831  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile],methods=[OPTIONS]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.profileOptions()
2017-07-13 19:41:40.831  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/schema+json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.JsonSchema> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySchemaController.schema(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-07-13 19:41:40.832  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/alps+json]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.alpsOptions()
2017-07-13 19:41:40.832  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/alps+json || */*]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.descriptor(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
2017-07-13 19:41:40.950  INFO 83740 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-07-13 19:41:40.999  INFO 83740 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-07-13 19:41:41.004  INFO 83740 --- [           main] c.b.s.customer.registration.Application  : Started Application in 4.291 seconds (JVM running for 7.001)
```

Comment: If that really is your yaml file the indentation is wrong.

Comment: probably copy-paste issues..I verified my yaml under http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: Can you share the startup log?  I'd expect to see the following:  2017-07-13 10:32:50.660  INFO 5520 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from URL [file:/C:/Users/blah/IdeaProjects/uuid/target/classes/data.sql]
2017-07-13 10:32:50.660  INFO 5520 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from URL [file:/C:/Users/blah/IdeaProjects/uuid/target/classes/data.sql] in 0 ms.

Comment: Well it is a valid yaml file but the indentation isn't correct. everything under datasource should be prefixed with 2 spaces else it will be ignored as it is an unknown property.

Comment: @M.Deinum url is picked up correctly

Comment: Any chance you could share a minimal example project on github?  I think that'll help us debug this.

Comment: Hey @zencv, you got solution?? Please share. I have exactly same issue now.

Comment: For troubleshooting it could help to debug your application at the startup, the class responsible of executing that script is : org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils, in the method executeSqlScript.. At the end you should see a message like: "Executed SQL script from " + resource + " in " + elapsedTime + " ms."

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Try adding this line in application.properties:

```
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

Or for Spring Boot before 2.5:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

Comment: Indeed default value is `embedded` which mean it only applies if you're running and embedded database. `always` is the solution if you're running an external database. Thanks!

Comment: For new spring boot version `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization: true`

Comment: thanks to @Cihangir, evenif data is loaded at ddl-auto: update mode, data sql cannot be loaded at ddl-auto: create-drop mode. After set the defer-datasource-initialization config, this problem was disappeared

Comment: Note that spring.datasource.initialization-mode has been replaced by spring.sql.init.mode

Comment: spring.sql.init.mode = always

Answer (score 19):

These two lines worked for me:

1. `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true`
2. `spring.sql.init.mode=always`

Unfortunately, the accepted answer `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always` is **deprecated**.

Comment: for me, the second line was adequate.

Comment: I wish I could give at least 100 upvotes. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Running on spring boot with azure tsql, spring.sql.init.mode=always is needed

Comment: If the datasource was initialized with an auto-commit to false
then the parameter spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true is needed.


"This will defer data source initialization until after any EntityManagerFactory beans have been created and initialized. schema.sql can then be used to make additions to any schema creation performed by Hibernate and data.sql can be used to populate it."

Comment: And for mentioning the data sql file location we can do `spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:accounts.sql, classpath:books.sql, file:reviews.sql`

Answer (score 10):

There may be other causes, but this will certainly stop it running:

```
ddl-auto: validate
```

Hibernate will only execute data.sql for create or create-drop; change to

```
ddl-auto: create
```

or

```
ddl-auto: create-drop
```

[Spring documentation on database initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate).

**[EDIT]** Hibernate WILL flatten your existing database with this setting - don't do this on production.

Comment: Thats not true- even with these settings, the database entries will be added at execution:

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Comment: Thanks. `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: validate` should be the default setting,

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

Please remember to not use 'create-drop' on production. It will drop your database after application stop.

Answer (score 8):

You should turn off automatic schema creation:

```
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

More information about initial loading data can be found here:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql

Answer (score 6):

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.data=classpath:Data.sql
```

I added these two and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

The property `spring.datasource.initialization-mode` is **deprecated** and according to the latest documents of spring boot database can be initialized with an sql file file named "import.sql";

> In addition, a file named ***import.sql*** in the root of the classpath is
> executed on startup if Hibernate creates the schema from scratch (that
> is, if the ddl-auto property is set to create or create-drop).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization

Comment: It is a Hibernate feature (and has nothing to do with Spring).

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Hibernate and for me it didn't work with a file named `data.sql`. I had to name it `import.sql`.

Other required settings are:

```
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

Answer (score 4):

You should try to set the following property `spring.datasource.platform` to `mysql`. Thus, Spring Boot will be able to load the `data-${platform}.sql` file.

You can find more details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc).

Comment: sorry, doesn't work. I had already tried just `data.sql` without any platform name as well, no luck

Comment: Bad indentation under the key `datasource` may causes the problem (yaml requires space indentation) ?
Nothing happens in the log output ?

Comment: yaml is fine as the app is working otherwise. Log output doesn't give any clues

Comment: Thomaas's indication + setting the followiing property  `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always` application.propertis worked for my configuration.

Answer (score 4):

I had to create two files: one for the schema and one for seed data.

```
src/
   main/
       resources/
                schema.sql
                data.sql
```

in schema.sql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
);
```

in data.sql:

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('nastysloper', 'password');
```

Answer (score 1):

SpringBoot 1.x.x

- Active by default
- spring.datasource.initialize=**true**/false
  [image]

SpringBoot 2.x.x

- Active by default for EMBEDDED Databases
- spring.datasource.initialization-mode=**embedded**/always/never
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact issue, below is my spring boot `application.properties file` .
-- If you are using a version greater that 2.0 , you need to use `import.sql` and not `data.sql`, the problem with `data.sql` was, it used to load data everytime the application starts.
The `import.sql` just works fine. I was using version `2.7.0`  of Spring Boot .

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Answer (score 0):

(Tried multiple ways, but at last this worked for me)
Try to update the application.properties file with below values:

```
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a SoftBlue course, BlueFood project and this code worked for me in Spring 4.19.0:

[Projeto BlueFood - Versão Spring ][4.19.0]

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false


spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bluefooddb
spring.datasource.username=bluefood
spring.datasource.password=test

spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:static/import.sql
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```